# How to avoid multiple instances of MediaPlayer objects?

Tags: android, android-mediaplayer

I'm devolping an music player application, when user click on an item (song) in the listview in PlayListFragment user redirects to the mediaPlayerFragment and the choosen melody starts to play. When user repeat the scenario i think that a new instance of mediaPlayer is created because there is two melodys playing at the same time.
How to avoid this problem?

(I have tried to place mediaPlayer.create(..) in onCreate() but there is probably something more that is need to be done to make it work correctly. I have also tried to create a singletonObject without success)

MediaPlayerFragment.java

```
public class MediaPlayerFragment extends  Fragment  {

private static final String ARG_PARAM1 = "param1";
private static final String ARG_PARAM2 = "param2";

// TODO: Rename and change types of parameters
private String mParam1;
private String mParam2;

private MediaPlayer mediaPlayer;
private double endTime = 0;
private double startTime = 0;
private int forwardTime = 5000;
private int backwardTime = 5000;
public static int oneTimeOnly = 0;

private SeekBar seekBar;

private ImageButton btnPlay;
private ImageButton btnPause;
private ImageButton btnStop;
private ImageButton btnForward;
private ImageButton btnRewind;

public TextView songInfo;
public TextView txtEndTime;
public TextView txtStartTime;

private Handler mediaHandler = new Handler();

private boolean isPausePressed = false;
private boolean isPlayPressed = false;
private boolean isStopPressed = true;

private OnFragmentInteractionListener mListener;
private Song currentSong;

public static MediaPlayerFragment newInstance(String param1, String param2) {
    MediaPlayerFragment fragment = new MediaPlayerFragment();
    Bundle args = new Bundle();
    args.putString(ARG_PARAM1, param1);
    args.putString(ARG_PARAM2, param2);
    fragment.setArguments(args);
    return fragment;
}

public MediaPlayerFragment() {
    // Required empty public constructor
}

@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    if (getArguments() != null) {
        mParam1 = getArguments().getString(ARG_PARAM1);
        mParam2 = getArguments().getString(ARG_PARAM2);
    }
}

@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                         Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    final View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_media_player,    container, false);

    getActivity().setTitle("Media Player");

    songInfo = (TextView)view.findViewById(R.id.txt_currentsong);
    txtEndTime = (TextView)view.findViewById(R.id.txt_time_left);
    txtStartTime = (TextView)view.findViewById(R.id.txt_time_start);
    seekBar = (SeekBar)view.findViewById(R.id.seek_bar_elapsed_time);

    btnPlay = (ImageButton)view.findViewById(R.id.btn_play);
    btnPause = (ImageButton)view.findViewById(R.id.btn_pause);
    btnStop = (ImageButton)view.findViewById(R.id.btn_stop);
    btnRewind = (ImageButton)view.findViewById(R.id.btn_previous);
    btnForward = (ImageButton)view.findViewById(R.id.btn_next);

    songInfo.setText(currentSong.getArtist() + " - " + currentSong.getTitle());

    mediaPlayer = MediaPlayer.create(getActivity(), Uri.parse(currentSong.getUri()));

    seekBar.setClickable(false);
    btnPause.setEnabled(false);
    btnStop.setEnabled(false);
    btnForward.setEnabled(false);
    btnRewind.setEnabled(false);

    //Click events!
    btnPause.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
                pause(view);
                isPausePressed = true;
                isPlayPressed = false;
                isStopPressed = false;
            }
        });

    btnPlay.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            play(view);
            isPausePressed = false;
            isPlayPressed = true;
            isStopPressed = false;
        }
    });

    btnStop.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            stop(view);
            isPausePressed = false;
            isPlayPressed = false;
            isStopPressed = true;
        }
    });

    btnForward.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            forward(view);
            isPausePressed = false;
            isPlayPressed = false;
            isStopPressed = false;
        }
    });

    btnRewind.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            rewind(view);
            isPausePressed = false;
            isPlayPressed = false;
            isStopPressed = false;
        }
    });

    seekBar.setOnSeekBarChangeListener(new SeekBar.OnSeekBarChangeListener() {

        @Override
        public void onStartTrackingTouch(SeekBar s) {

        }

        @Override
        public void onStopTrackingTouch(SeekBar s) {

        }

        @Override
        public void onProgressChanged(SeekBar s, int progress, boolean fromUser) {
            if (mediaPlayer != null && fromUser) {
                mediaPlayer.seekTo(progress);

                // Check if pause, play or stop buttons is pressed
                if(!isPausePressed && !isPlayPressed && !isStopPressed) {
                    play(view);
                }
            }
        }

    });

    return view;
}

public void play(View view) {
    //Check if a track has been choosen from playlist...
    if(currentSong.getId() != null) {
        mediaPlayer.start();
        endTime = mediaPlayer.getDuration();
        startTime = mediaPlayer.getCurrentPosition();
        if (oneTimeOnly == 0) {
            seekBar.setMax((int) endTime);
            oneTimeOnly = 1;
        }

        txtEndTime.setText(String.format("%d min, %d sec",
                        TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS.toMinutes((long) endTime),
                        TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS.toSeconds((long) endTime) -
                                TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS.toSeconds(TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS.toMinutes((long) endTime)))
        );

        txtStartTime.setText(String.format("%d min, %d sec",
                        TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS.toMinutes((long) startTime),
                        TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS.toSeconds((long) startTime) -
                                TimeUnit.MINUTES.toSeconds(TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS.toMinutes((long) startTime)))
        );

        seekBar.setProgress((int) startTime);
        mediaHandler.postDelayed(UpdateSongTime, 100);

        btnPause.setEnabled(true);
        btnStop.setEnabled(true);
        btnRewind.setEnabled(true);
        btnForward.setEnabled(true);
    }
}

private Runnable UpdateSongTime = new Runnable() {
    public void run() {
        startTime = mediaPlayer.getCurrentPosition();
        txtStartTime.setText(String.format("%d min, %d sec",
                        TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS.toMinutes((long) startTime),
                        TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS.toSeconds((long) startTime),
                        TimeUnit.MINUTES.toSeconds(TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS.toMinutes((long) startTime)))
        );
        seekBar.setProgress((int) startTime);
        mediaHandler.postDelayed(this, 100);
    }
};

public void stop(View view) {
    btnPause.setEnabled(false);
    btnForward.setEnabled(false);
    btnRewind.setEnabled(false);
    btnStop.setEnabled(false);

    mediaPlayer.pause();
    mediaPlayer.seekTo(0);
}

public void pause(View view) {
    mediaPlayer.pause();
    btnPause.setEnabled(false);
    btnPlay.setEnabled(true);
}

public void forward(View view) {
    int temp = (int)startTime;
    if ((temp + forwardTime)<= endTime) {
        startTime = startTime + forwardTime;
        mediaPlayer.seekTo((int) startTime);
    }
}

public void rewind(View view) {
    int temp = (int) startTime;
    if ((temp-backwardTime)> 0) {
        startTime = startTime - backwardTime;
        mediaPlayer.seekTo((int)startTime);
    }
}

public void setSong(Song song) {
    this.currentSong = song;
}

// TODO: Rename method, update argument and hook method into UI event
public void onButtonPressed(Uri uri) {
    if (mListener != null) {
        mListener.onFragmentInteraction(uri);
    }
}

@Override
public void onAttach(Activity activity) {
    super.onAttach(activity);
    try {
        mListener = (OnFragmentInteractionListener) activity;
    } catch (ClassCastException e) {
        throw new ClassCastException(activity.toString()
                + " must implement OnFragmentInteractionListener");
    }
}

@Override
public void onDetach() {
    super.onDetach();
    mListener = null;
}

public interface OnFragmentInteractionListener {
    // TODO: Update argument type and name
    public void onFragmentInteraction(Uri uri);
}
```

}

PlayListFragment.java

```
public class PlayListFragment extends Fragment {

private static final String ARG_PARAM1 = "param1";
private static final String ARG_PARAM2 = "param2";

// TODO: Rename and change types of parameters
private String mParam1;
private String mParam2;

private PlayListAdapter playListAdapter;
private ListView lstPlayList;
public static ArrayList<Song> storeSongs = new ArrayList<>();

private OnFragmentInteractionListener mListener;

public static PlayListFragment newInstance(String param1, String param2) {
    PlayListFragment fragment = new PlayListFragment();
    Bundle args = new Bundle();
    args.putString(ARG_PARAM1, param1);
    args.putString(ARG_PARAM2, param2);
    fragment.setArguments(args);
    return fragment;
}

public PlayListFragment() {
    // Required empty public constructor
}

@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    if (getArguments() != null) {
        mParam1 = getArguments().getString(ARG_PARAM1);
        mParam2 = getArguments().getString(ARG_PARAM2);
    }
}

@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                         Bundle savedInstanceState) {

    // Inflate the layout for this fragment
    View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_play_list, container, false);

    getActivity().setTitle("Play List");

    getSongList();
    sort(storeSongs);
    AddToListView(view);

    lstPlayList.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {
            Song song = new Song();

            //Get clicked song from listview.
            song = (Song) parent.getAdapter().getItem(position);


            changeToMediaPlayerFragment(song);

        }
    });

    return view;
}

private void getSongList() {
    ContentResolver musicResolver = getActivity().getContentResolver();
    Uri musicUri = MediaStore.Audio.Media.EXTERNAL_CONTENT_URI;
    Cursor musicCursor = musicResolver.query(musicUri, null, null, null, null);

    if (musicCursor != null && musicCursor.moveToFirst()) {
        //get columns
        int titleColumns = musicCursor.getColumnIndex( MediaStore.Audio.Media.TITLE);
        int idColumn = musicCursor.getColumnIndex(MediaStore.Audio.Media._ID);
        int artistColumn = musicCursor.getColumnIndex(MediaStore.Audio.Media.ARTIST);
        int uriColumn = musicCursor.getColumnIndex(MediaStore.Audio.Media.DATA);

        //Add songs to container (storeSongs).
        do {
            Long thisId = musicCursor.getLong(idColumn);
            String thisTitle = musicCursor.getString(titleColumns);
            String thisArtist = musicCursor.getString(artistColumn);
            String thisUri = musicCursor.getString(uriColumn);

            storeSongs.add(new Song(thisId, thisTitle, thisArtist, thisUri));

        } while (musicCursor.moveToNext());

    }
}

public void changeToMediaPlayerFragment(Song song) {
    MediaPlayerFragment mediaPlayerFragment = MediaPlayerFragment.newInstance("", "");
    mediaPlayerFragment.setSong(song);
    FragmentManager fM = getFragmentManager();
    FragmentTransaction fT = fM.beginTransaction();
    fT.replace(R.id.container, mediaPlayerFragment, null);
    fT.addToBackStack("go to mediaPlayer fragmement");
    fT.commit();
}

private void AddToListView(View view) {
    if (playListAdapter == null) {
        playListAdapter = new PlayListAdapter(getActivity(), storeSongs);
    }

    this.lstPlayList = (ListView) view.findViewById(R.id.listView_play_list);

    lstPlayList.setAdapter(playListAdapter);
    playListAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
}

private void sort(ArrayList<Song> songs) {
    Collections.sort(songs, new Comparator<Song>() {
        @Override
        public int compare(Song lhs, Song rhs) {
            return lhs.getArtist().compareTo(rhs.getArtist());
        }
    });
}

// TODO: Rename method, update argument and hook method into UI event
public void onButtonPressed(Uri uri) {
    if (mListener != null) {
        mListener.onFragmentInteraction(uri);
    }
}

@Override
public void onAttach(Activity activity) {
    super.onAttach(activity);
    try {
        mListener = (OnFragmentInteractionListener) activity;
    } catch (ClassCastException e) {
        throw new ClassCastException(activity.toString()
                + " must implement OnFragmentInteractionListener");
    }
}

@Override
public void onDetach() {
    super.onDetach();
    mListener = null;
}


public interface OnFragmentInteractionListener {
    // TODO: Update argument type and name
    public void onFragmentInteraction(Uri uri);
}
```

}

Comment: I am not a 100% certain of this so I will not post this as an answer but here is my two cents: As I see it, whenever a new song is chosen you create a completely new MediaPlayerFragment, and as such a new media player. This will make the music overlap as more and more players are added with each new song pressed. A way to improve this is for the Activity to create an instance of both fragments and hold a reference to these. Then whenever a new song is chosen, the PlaylistFragment will tell the Activity, and the Activity will tell the MediaPlayerFragment to change its song.

Answer (score 0):

As Dyrborg pointed out i have now made the activity responsible for holding one reference to PlayListFragment and one reference of the MediaPlayerFragment.

```
public void changeToPlayListFragment() {
    if (playListFragment == null) {
        playListFragment = PlayListFragment.newInstance("", "");
    }

    if (getCurrentFragment() == 2) {
        return;
    } else {
        FragmentManager fME = getFragmentManager();
        FragmentTransaction fTE = fME.beginTransaction();
        fTE.replace(R.id.container, playListFragment, null);
        fTE.addToBackStack("go to Playlist fragment");
        fTE.commit();
    }
}

 private int getCurrentFragment() {
    Fragment currentFragment = getFragmentManager().findFragmentById(R.id.container);
    if (currentFragment instanceof MediaPlayerFragment) {
        return 1;
    } else if (currentFragment instanceof  PlayListFragment) {
        return 2;
    } else {
        return 0;
    }
}
```

Link contains all *java* code for a simple light weight media player with knocking interaction "http://pastebin.com/BHVZYLGv"